# How can I import lots of C-files into my project in QT?

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt5

QT runs C++ and I want to import C-files and H-files into my project.
Is there a way do to that graphically in QT Creator?

I made a CAN-bus SAE J1939 project made in 100% C code and I want to import all these files into my QT project. The C-files are written with C99 style that works with C++ as well.

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Open-SAE-J1939

Comment: Qt is written in C++ and it has some binding to other languages ... BTW, the best way is to use a build system or build system generator, to exactly specify the files you need then include them using `#include` preprocess directive. Wildcards are not supported.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani But do I need to do that manually? Isn't that something QT Creator can do for me?

Comment: Yes, you need to do it manually. But you could write a simple script to do it for you.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani Thank you. Do I need to rename `.c` to `.cpp` too?

Comment: No, but if you need the C-Linkage, you also need to wrap `#include`es into an `extern "C" { }` block